# Not connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to connect to a mysql database within a php script. So far, my code looks like

```
//to my knowledge, this works. I was able to echo out the correct name
$name = $_POST["name"];


$server_name = "localhost"; 
$user_name = //my user name
$password = //my password
$db_name = //the db name

//it passes this error check, so I am connecting properly I am assuming 
$dbconn = mysql_connect($server_name, $user_name, $password) 
    or die ('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_name, $dbconn);

$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM brothers 
          WHERE name = '$name'";

//it DOES NOT make it past this one
$result = mysql_query($query)
    or die('Bad Query: ' . mysql_error());

//filter through the query as a row
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

//echo the result back to the user
echo $row["name"];
echo $row["major"];


//close the connection 
mysql_close($dbconn);
```

I keep getting the error "No Database Selected", even though I am sure that I spelled the database name correctly (I copy pasted). Does anyone know why my code might be throwing this error?

Comment: Where are you mentioning the database name in the above code ?

Comment: Are you sure your database login details are correct

Comment: Do the same `or die ('Could not use DB: ' . mysql_error())` after the `mysql_select_db()` call to find out what's going on there.

Comment: $db_name... I wasn't sure about actually putting that code up for all to see, but I initialize it here 


$db_name = //the db name

Comment: Are you sure that the database actually exists on the MySQL server you're connecting to? If it does exist, does the user you're connecting with have the right permissions to access that database? Try using the mysql command line client to do the same thing your code is doing to determine if it's your code (which appears to be fine) or if it's the database permissions/settings.

Comment: double check ALL your db info. PW, username, db name etc

Comment: You should really sanitze $name. Your code is wide open to an injection.

Comment: Verify that `mysql_select_db` actually selects a database by checking its return value, which is `FALSE` on failure.

Comment: access denied error.. but it wasn't throwing up any errors for


$dbconn = mysql_connect($server_name, $user_name, $password) 
    or die ('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: @Zack: that's because you have permission to connect to the DB server but not the actual database. A server can have multiple databases on it.

Comment: You can easily get an access denied error for a database, even though you can connect to the database. Not every user on a database server has access to every database.

Comment: does anyone know how to change permissions for a DB in cpanel?

Comment: where in phpMyAdmin would I find the permission settings?

Comment: nvmd got it. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a permissions issue(the user which logon maybe don't have read rights on the database) :

> mysql_select_db() fails unless the connected user can be authenticated
>   as having permission to use the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my comment in answer form:

Do the same `or die ('Could not use DB: ' . mysql_error())` after the `mysql_select_db()` call to find out what's going on there.

Your comment ("access denied") suggests that you have permissions to connect to the database server but not to use the database. Remember that one database server can have multiple databases on it, each with their own permission scheme. Check the permissions on the database you're trying to use and make sure that `$user_name` can use it with `$password`.